# Keyboard pre-boot doesn't work properly

Tags: keyboard, bios, bitlocker, veracrypt

I want to encrypt my windows but I cannot because when typing the password at boot, it types multiple characters for each click. E.g. typing "Hello" will type actually "HheeeLllloooooooo".

I have tried my Corsair gaming keyboard (USB) and also another wireless keyboard. I have tried both BitLocker and VeraCrypt. When I type *very* slowly, it types letter by letter, which is annoying with every boot. I tried many things like disable fast boot in BIOS/UEFI and in windows also. Enabled legacy usb in BIOS/UEFI. Reinstalled BIOS, etc…

I have the MSI Z87-G45 with BIOS 1.9 2014-07-22, this is the latest available.

Is there any other way to test the keyboard before windows boots to see if the typing is only when typing passwords for BitLocker/VeraCrypt?

How can I fix this? I am on Windows 10 with latest updates.

Comment: Try a substitute keyboard.  That is what I do.

Comment: I also tried a wireless keyboard, same results

Comment: Strange. If the Operating System works well with keyboard, then there may be a BIOS issue.

Comment: Which encryption ? bitlocker or  veracrypt ?

Comment: I tried both. seems to be bios, in windows it works fine. but there are no new bios updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was to switch the keyboard switch to BIOS mode (Corsair K70). This will switch it to be compatible with BIOS etc. Then I could type the password normally. For a keyboard to work in BIOS it needs to be apparently a regular 104-key keyboard. By switching to BIOS mode on mine, it does this, but also reduces the polling rate and disables advances features.